Erewhon Birthday Problem
Problem: Labor laws in Erewhon require factory owners to give every worker a holiday when any one of them has a birthday (and to hire without discrimination on grounds on birthdays). Except for these birthday holidays, the workers work a 365-day year. How many workers should the factory hire to maximize the number of man-days worked?
My solution:
Suppose the factory has $N$ workers. Let $X_i$ be an indicator variable for whether worker $i$ has a distinct birthday from the rest. $P(X_i = 1) = \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{N-1}$ (because each of the $N-1$ other workers must have a different birthday), so $E(X_i) = \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{N-1}$.
Therefore, total number of expected distinct birthdays is $\sum_{i=1}^N E(X_i)$ because the linearity of expectation allows us to ignore that $\{X_i\}$ are not independent. Therefore, expected number of man days worked $$=365N - N\times \sum_{i=1}^N E(X_i) = 365N - N^2\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{N-1}$$ However, this function does not have a maxima. Logically though, there has to be a maximum $N$ because when $N$ is really high it is almost certain that there is a birthday everyday so the factory never works.
Where am I faltering?

Not sure why you are focusing on workers with unique birthdays.  Better, it seems to me, is to look at the days themselves.  Let $Y_i$ be the indicator variable which tells you if some worker has a birthday on day $i$.  So $E[Y_i]=1-\left(\frac {364}{365}\right)^N$.  Go from there.

Right, that is the solution given and that's easily calculable. But I don't understand why my solution is incorrect?

For the reason I said.  The number of workers with unique birthdays is irrelevant to the problem.  Of course that number is expected to go to $0$ for large $N$, but so what?

I think upon giving it some more thought, and I'd like you to correct me if I'm wrong, the above method would only work if number of workers with unique birthdays = number of days with at least one birthday. But take 5 workers, where worker 2 and 3 share a birthday, worker 4 and 5 share a different birthday and worker 1 has a third different birthday. In that case, number of days with at least one birthday = 3 $\ne$ number of workers with unique birthday =1 ?

Well, that's an odd way to put it.  They are simply unrelated concepts.  the rules direct us to look at those dates on which some worker has a birthday.  Makes no difference if  it is $1$ worker or $1000$ workers.  But, I agree with your instincts to look at smaller examples.  That is always a good idea.

To stress:  the expected number of days on which some worker has a birthday goes to $365$ for large $N$, while the expected number of workers who have a unique birthday goes to $0$.

As lulu commented, there is a holiday if anybody that day has a birthday that day, not just when exactly one person has a birthday.
With the usual assumptions, the probability a particular day is not a holiday is then  $\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^N$,  so the expected total number of person-days worked is $365\;N\; \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^N$ by linearity of expectation.
If you see where this is an increasing or decreasing function of the number of workers by considering the change $365\;N\; \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^N -365\;(N-1)\; \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{N-1} = (365-N) \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{N-1}$ when you add an extra worker, then the expected total number of person-days worked is maximised when $N=364$ or $N=365$, at which point it is about $48943.52$.

Side note:  It seems to me that, given that the answer is (essentially) $365$, namely the total number of days, that should be obvious somehow.  Is it? Of course it drops out of the calculation, but can you see it directly?

@lulu - I don't know if it is intuitive but each extra worker multiplies the expected number of working days by $\frac{364}{365}$ while the $365$th worker multiples the number of workers by $\frac{365}{364}$ and so this is the point where the two effects offset each other.

Not bad.  $\quad$
